# Joining a large number of tables so that all dates are kept

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have around 50-70 tables that look very similar, say:

Table 1:

```
id   | date     |    count_A   |   count_B
1    12.05.2021        12            15
```

Table 2:

```
id   | date     |    count_A   |   count_B
1    15.05.2021        8            24
```

The main table looks like the following:

```
id    |   label
1          X
```

In the end, what I would like to get is:

```
id    |   date   |   count_A     |  count_B   |   label
1      12.05.2021     12             15            X
1      15.05.2021     8              24            X
```

One intuitive approach is to use the full outer join and join on `id` but that would result in strange rows with several date values.
Joining on `(id, date)` doesn't seem to be a great option either.

What can be a possible solution here? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the  “UNION” statement. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#union_example

Comment: They are not guaranteed to have the same column sets

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted or upvote. This can help future users who are having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery with the statement [WITH](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause). Inside this subquery, you can use the [UNION](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#union_example) with all the tables with the same schema.
Use a join statement between the subquery, in this case tablaC and the main table, which has a different schema.

You can see this example:

```
WITH tablaC AS (
SELECT ID,date,count_C,Count_D  FROM Table_C
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,date,count_C,Count_D FROM Table_D
)
 
select c.ID,date,c.count_C,c.Count_D,m.label 
from tablaC  as c
join table_main as m on c.id=m.id
```

[image]